# How to crawler apps.apple without knowing the app names?

Tags: web-crawler, app-store, itunes

I want to crawl some app info from apps.apple, and if I know the app name, I can get it through this api:

```
url = "http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=" + app + "&entity=software"
```

However, I don't know the specific app names, but maybe only the category. For example, I want to get all games. Is there a way to crawl those games without knowing their names?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the Enterprise Partner Feed - you can download all the metadata for apps and create your own database to query.

https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-enterprise-partner-feed/